# List the branch that monthly pays the most in salaries

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have this table, the expected output should be B003 since it's pays 54,000

| STAFF | SALARY | BRAN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SL21 | 30000 | B005 |
| SG37 | 12000 | B003 |
| SG14 | 18000 | B003 |
| SA9 | 9000 | B007 |
| SG5 | 24000 | B003 |
| SL41 | 9000 | B005 |

So far I only have this subquery, which isn't working how I expected.

```
SELECT BRANCHNO
FROM STAFF
WHERE (SALARY)  IN (SELECT MAX(SUM(SALARY))
                FROM STAFF
                GROUP BY BRANCHNO);
```

This works but I want a subquery that returns the branchno

```
SELECT MAX(SUM(SALARY))
FROM STAFF
GROUP BY BRANCHNO;
```

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, ORDER BY, FETCH FIRST.

Answer (score 0):

```
select BRANCHNO max(sum_sal) 
from (SELECT BRANCHNO, SUM(SALARY) sum_sal
        FROM STAFF
    GROUP BY BRANCHNO) q1
group by BRANCHNO ;
```

The column used to group the rows can be displayed. So, add BRANCHNO to your select clause.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `rank` analytic function which *ranks* branches by sum of their salaries in descending order; you'd then return the one(s) that rank as the *highest* (`rnk = 1`).

Sample data:

```
SQL> with staff (staff, salary, bran) as
  2    (select 'SL21', 30000, 'B005' from dual union all
  3     select 'SG37', 12000, 'B003' from dual union all
  4     select 'SG14', 18000, 'B003' from dual union all
  5     select 'SA9' ,  9000, 'B007' from dual union all
  6     select 'SG5' , 24000, 'B003' from dual union all
  7     select 'SL41',  9000, 'B005' from dual
  8    )
```

Query:

```
  9  select bran
 10  from (select bran, rank() over (order by sum(salary) desc) rnk
 11        from staff
 12        group by bran
 13       )
 14  where rnk = 1;

BRAN
----
B003

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked for me.